# Parallelizing large sum to use all cpu cores

Tags: performance-tuning

I'm looking to compute the the following expectation, with $x$ a column vector sampled from $d$-dimensional distribution.

$$E[(I-\alpha xx')\text{cov}(I-\alpha xx')]$$

Simple example is below. `samples` controls number of $x$'s sampled, and the issue is that when `samples` is large compared to $d$, Mathematica doesn't use all cpu cores -- I'm only seeing utilization on a single core. How do I make this computation better parallelized?

````
samples = 1000000;
alpha = 0.5;
d = 2;
ii = IdentityMatrix[d];
cov = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {d, d}];
X = {{0, 3}, {2, 0}, {-1, -1}};
batchStepCov :=
  
  Mean[(ii - alpha Outer[Times, #, #]).cov.(ii - 
        alpha Outer[Times, #, #]) & /@ RandomChoice[X, samples]];
batchStepCov // Timing
```
````

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that there is no need for parallelization. The following piece of code generates the same numbers with a considerably less amount of computational effort. It is about 100 times faster than your implementation.

```
f = With[{A = ii - alpha Outer[Times, #, #]}, A.cov.A] &
mats =  f/@ X;
Dot[
 SortBy[Tally[RandomChoice[Range[Length[X]], samples]], First][[All, 2]],
 mats
 ]/samples
```

The main idea: There are only three different matrices in `X`, so there are only three possible matrices in `f /@ X`. Sampling from `X` and applying `f` has the same effect as sampling directly from `mats = f /@ X` -- but without having to recompute `f` all the time.
But even better: You do not need to have to evaluate `RandomChoice[mats, samples]`; it suffices to know how often each matrix from `mats` is drawn. The random vector of the frequencies can be obtained with

```
SortBy[Tally[RandomChoice[Range[Length[X]], samples]], First][[All, 2]]]
```

and from there you compute the mean by `Dot`ting against `mats` and dividing by the number of samples.

In fact, you can also get around computing

```
SortBy[Tally[RandomChoice[Range[Length[X]], samples]], First][[All, 2]]]
```

(which is the only really time consuming part) by observing that this vector follows a `MultinomialDistribution`. The following takes only 0.4 milliseconds and should have the same effect:

```
mats = With[{A = ii - alpha Outer[Times, #, #]}, A.cov.A] & /@ X;
Dot[
  RandomVariate[
   MultinomialDistribution[
    samples, 
    ConstantArray[1/Length[X], {Length[X]}]]
    ],
  mats
  ]/samples
```